# Deleting a marker from the android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I'm having a lot of trouble deleting a marker from my database, specifically the table of markers. Currently, I'm creating a new MapsMarker (Object seen below) and getting the long result by inserting it into my table, then using this result to get the ID for deletion. But this isn't working since using the .insert method adds an extra marker to my database. So my question is, how can I properly delete the markers from the database without (or with, either way works) the use of .insert, since this adds a new marker to my database.

```
Here is my AddMarker method:

/**
     * Method for adding a marker to the database and returning its ID if needed (for deletion, find, etc.)
     * @param marker
     * @return
     */
    public long addMapsMarker(MapsMarker marker) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Dont .put COLUMN_MARKER_ID because it is autoincrementing
        values.put(DBQueryModelHelper.COLUMN_LAT, marker.getLat());
        values.put(DBQueryModelHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, marker.getLong());

        long result = SQDatabase.insert(DBQueryModelHelper.TABLE_LOCATION, null, values);
        //marker.setId(result);
        marker.setId(result - 1); //sets the added marker ID to the row ID where it was inserted (same value as the autoincrementing ID)
        long bb = marker.getId();
        return result;
}

My delete method:

   /**
     * Method for deleting a marker, currently deletes from database but marker is reloaded.
     * @param marker
     */
    public void deleteMapsMarker(MapsMarker marker){
        long id = marker.getId();
        SQDatabase.delete(DBQueryModelHelper.TABLE_LOCATION, DBQueryModelHelper.COLUMN_MARKER_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
    }
```

My MapsMarker object is an object that holds a latitude and longitude, but also has a private id and all the getters and setters for these fields.

And here is my Map Activity where I am attempting the delete:

```
public void setUsermarker() {
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
                    .setMessage("View imagery or delete this marker?")
                            //Delete user marker
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete Marker", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            marker.remove();
                            MapsMarker markerforDelete = new MapsMarker(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude);
                            long tablerowid = MarkerHelper.addMapsMarker(markerforDelete);
                            markerforDelete.setId(tablerowid);

                            MarkerHelper.deleteMapsMarker(markerforDelete);
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("View 3D", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        // Start 3D view activity
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, BuildingViewActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, a better approach would be to write modular code instead of putting all together. Using content providers are a better idea when you do want to perform the insert/delete options frequently after a callback is called.

Create a class that would store the location in DB with the help of Content Providers on the top of DB class that would simplify the overall process.

```
/** A custom Content Provider to do the database operations */
public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.mapv2.demo.locations";

    /** A uri to do operations on locations table. A content provider is identified by its uri */
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );

    /** Constant to identify the requested operation */
    private static final int LOCATIONS = 1;    

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);        
    }

    /** This content provider does the database operations by this object */
    LocationsDB mLocationsDB;

    /** A callback method which is invoked when the content provider is starting up */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    /** A callback method which is invoked when insert operation is requested on this content provider */
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        long rowID = mLocationsDB.insert(values);
        Uri _uri=null;
        if(rowID>0){
            _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
        }else {        
            try {
                throw new SQLException("Failed to insert : " + uri);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return _uri;    
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    /** A callback method which is invoked when delete operation is requested on this content provider */
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int cnt = 0;        
        cnt = mLocationsDB.del();    
        return cnt;
    }

    /** A callback method which is invoked by default content uri */
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {    

        if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==LOCATIONS){
            return mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {        
        return null;
    }    
}
```

From the front end you can query the database using a separate thread to get the content resolver and then either insert or delete.

```
  private class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {

            /** Setting up values to insert the clicked location into SQLite database */           
            getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);            
            return null;
        }        
    }

    private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            /** Deleting all the locations stored in SQLite database */
            getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);            
            return null;
        }        
    }
```

For additional information you can go over this [tutorial](http://androidmapv2.blogspot.com/2013/11/storing-and-retrieving-locations-in.html).

Comment: Gonna try this out and will get back to you once I've implemented it!